# Prevent users from creating a directory in git locally

Tags: git

An odd question.

I'm managing a git mono repo, where I don't want general users to be able to create new applications in the git repository, I want to stop them even creating this folder / files locally (If they get to the stage of being ready to commit on their branch then they've come too far).

The caveat here, if the folder has been created then they should be able to create new files in the directory / take ownership of that directory.

I had some ideas around maintaining a list of allowed applications in the repository itself and checking for files / directories being created via a git hook, however there doesn't seem to be a hook for this.

To summarize

- Prevent user from creating folders in a given repository unless I've created it for them / the folder is on a list of allowed folders
- This should prevent them from ever creating it locally, not just on commit

Interested in any ideas you may have on how to achieve this. User education isn't an option, they can't be trusted.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you not prevent folder creation locally, you also cannot enforce the use of commit hooks, and you also can't stop someone from committing whatever they want locally.

**The place to stop it is on the *server*.** You could either implement pre-push hooks on the server to block any pushes that don't meet your criteria, or, perhaps the more common approach is to let users push whatever they want on their own personal branches, but use status checks (aka "gated checkins") on PRs/MRs into any protected branches. Those status checks could disallow any merges into specific branches, unless all requirements are met.

Note, once you implement rules on the *server* in the form of either pre-push hooks or status checks, you can still offer pre-commit hooks to the users to help them not break the rules, but you cannot force them to use the hooks.

**Side Note:** it used to be sort of strange to use the word "server" in the context of a Git repo, since Git is distributed. However, nowadays most shared Git repos are hosted in a centralized location where Git-hooks and/or protected branches are common-place. In repos of this nature there is a generally agreed upon "source of truth" repo, which everyone shares.

Comment: Unfortunately whilst this works on preventing the user from pushing the change to the server side, my main aim here is that they don't waste time in the first place creating these folders / applications only to find out it won't be potentially ever accepted. Rather they can't create the folder and reach out to help as to why they can't for the education phase. I tried to manage this also via the folder modes `chmod -w` however git unfortunately (fortunately?) does not manage / track this mode permission.

Comment: @Iamterribleatcoding in that case you can provide a pre-commit hook which warns or prevents from committing changes to those folders, and show them how to install the hooks. It would be up to them whether they decide to take the help or not. ;)

Comment: It may be what it comes down to, but if they're at the stage of committing, the damage is done. They've wasted time creating an directory that may not be accepted. Whilst I'd love to put it on the users responsibility, this is my responsibility to ensure that the user can't make this mistake, and education in this part is very likely to be ignored / looked over by the user in favour of how easy it is just to create a new directory.

Comment: @Iamterribleatcoding if it truly is devastating when someone creates a folder, then you may consider controlling their machine file permissions. Maybe give them a virtual machine to work in that already has the repo cloned with the proper file structure, and then restrict their user so that it cannot create new folders in that directory. The "thing" you provide them would be the VM instead of a repo.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Git can do. New files and directories within an existing repo are untracked, so Git won't do anything with them until someone runs `git add` - and, by your stated objective, that's too late.

If you want to restrict directory creation within a specific folder, then you'll need to rely on operating system tools.

Comment: There is the possibility for possibly having a post checkout hook here that will change the permissions of that particular directory. I'll give this a go

Comment: @Iamterribleatcoding Non-cooperating user can avoid installing the hook, or edit it, or remove. There is no way to force a user to do anything on the client side.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question. Non-cooperating users are fine, this mechanism is meant as a way of preventing users from wasting their time, so benefits abiding users.

Comment: You'd still need to get the hook onto their systems, though, and you'd need to have some way to handle things when the hook isn't running for whatever reason.

Comment: Yeah am reading up on this now. I had thought git provided methods of executing hooks after an initial clone but naturally this looks like it would be a security concern and isn't possible. Back to the drawing board...